# Displaying a percentage as an integer

Tags: python, integer, percentage

New to Python, but how is this not yielding an integer >.< I added the int in front of the values in hope that by setting them specifically as ints I wouldn't get 40.0% back  I'd just like it to say 40%

```
score = 4
opLimit = 10
total = int(100) * int(score)/int(oqLimit)
print(total,"%")
```

Comment: `int * int` is `int`; and then `int / int` is `float`. You want `int(100*score/oqLimit)`.

Comment: Just did it a different way dude, regardless of what value the answer is I displayed it as an int with
 
    print(int(total),"%")

Comment: You definitely should accept Adam's answer, as it gives you the fastest (no casting) & more Pythonic (readable) way to do what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Python3, you should use string formatting.

```
score = 4
opLimit = 10
total = 100 * score/oqLimit
print("{:.0f}%".format(total))
# {...} defines a substitution field
#   :...  defines the formatting options
#    .0f    indicates to represent floats with 0 digits after the decimal
```

Comment: @MattNewton if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.